# how get RAY stake amount and reward details

Tags: web3js, solana, solana-web3js

i need to get details of staked RAY on raydium program for my app and im using:

```
        .getParsedProgramAccounts( new PublicKey(
  "EhhTKczWMGQt46ynNeRX1WfeagwwJd7ufHvCDjRxjo5Q")
, {
          filters: [
            {
              memcmp: {
                offset: 12,
                bytes: owner.toBase58(),
              },
            },
          ],
        })
```

but it return empty array

return staked details